# How to enable RUM for Apache static content in newrelic

Tags: newrelic

Is there a way to enable real user monitoring (RUM) for web applications which are served by Apache as static content.

Basically what I have is an Apache HTTP server proxy a tomcat server. But only the requests with prefix /api go to tomcat. HTML is served by apache and not tomcat. My newrelic java agent is in tomcat.

Is it at all possible to instrument these files? If yes, how can I generate the required javascript headers and footers for manual instrumentation in this scenario?.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Browser page timing requires that javacript insertion(s) be added to the page of interest (headers and in some case footers).  The insert is time and process sensitive and is accomplished by the New Relic agent for the language that is being used.  There is no technique available for manual instrumentation of a static page.

Comment: Which begs the question: why?